# Move "in stock" up on Woocommerce product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to move "in stock" just underneath the price rather than after the product short description.

What I don't get is that on my `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/price.php`.

The code seems to do just that :

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

<p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>

<meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_price() ); ?>" />
<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php echo esc_attr( get_woocommerce_currency() ); ?>" />
<link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/<?php echo $product->is_in_stock() ? 'InStock' : 'OutOfStock'; ?>" />
```

But when I'm on my product page, the description somehow comes in between : 
http://www.taldeak.fr/shop/rugby/pays-de-galles-france-cardiff-26-28-fevrier-2016

I know it's in French but basically price and stock are the only two infos in green. FYI, I'm using the WooCommerce - Gravity Forms Product Add-Ons, in case it's relevant.

If anyone could help, it would be great !!
Thanks in advance,
G

Comment: If one or more answers are correct you should accept (and upvote if appropriate) one so other users of this site know which one is best and correctly answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have moved your link tag for the `itemprop="availablity"`, which is showing in the html within the `itemprop="offers"` however you have not moved the actual stock html that is contained within `<p class="stock in-stock">`

This is the current content around the code you provided

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <p class="price"><span class="woocommerce-price-before"><font><font>from € 849 </font></font></span><span class="woocommerce-price-after"> </span></p>
<meta itemprop="price" content="0">
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR">
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">
</div>
```

**Edit:** The stock status is included in two places, depending on whether it is a simple or grouped product:

`wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php` line 22

```
<?php
    // Availability
    $availability      = $product->get_availability();
    $availability_html = empty( $availability['availability'] ) ? '' : '<p class="stock ' . esc_attr( $availability['class'] ) . '">' . esc_html( $availability['availability'] ) . '</p>';

    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_stock_html', $availability_html, $availability['availability'], $product );
?>
```

`wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/grouped.php` line 62

```
<?php
    echo $product->get_price_html();

    if ( $availability = $product->get_availability() ) {
        $availability_html = empty( $availability['availability'] ) ? '' : '<p class="stock ' . esc_attr( $availability['class'] ) . '">' . esc_html( $availability['availability'] ) . '</p>';
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_stock_html', $availability_html, $availability['availability'], $product );
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply Tristan. I had indeed seen that the <p class="stock in-stock"> was misplaced on the html. But I don't know where to edit it, since there isn't any more code below what I sent earlier. That's the end of the price.php template.